# Paypal ios6 issue

Tags: iphone, ios6, paypal

While trying all the steps for integration with paypal in my application it showing the following Error,
[image]

I include all the frame works ,

```
 AVFoundation.framework
 AudioToolbox.framework
 CoreMedia.framework
 CoreVideo.framework
 libxml2.dylib
 MessageUI.framework
 MobileCoreServices.framework
 OpenGLES.framework
 QuartzCore.framework
 Security.framework
 UIKit.framework
```

Can any one help me to sort out.Please

Comment: Looks like you need remove `i386` from `Architectures` and `Valid Architectures` in Xcode Build

Comment: @08442 i did , still showing the same error

Comment: once do cmd+shift+k and run again

Comment: @08442 Still showing the same

Comment: @CAMOBAP how to remove??

Comment: Firstly, do you have `i386` in `Architectures` or in `Valid Architectures` in Build Settings tab?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer  `Build Settings, added -lstdc++ -ObjC to Other Linker Flags.`